# Problema con buscaminas JAVA

Tags: java

Hola necesito ayuda urgente. Hace apenas 4 meses que me he iniciado de 0 en la programación dentro de un ciclo superior sin tener idea y me gusta pero me esta costando bastante. La cosa es que nos han hecho realizar un buscaminas por consola en Java, y he hecho tablero, puesto las minas y casillas libres, y nivel de dificultad. Pero ahora viene la parte más dificil a mi parecer. Debemos controlar cuantas minas hay en las 8 posiciones de al rededor del tablero dependiendo donde la persona selecione fila y columna, he ido sumando y restando posiciones en la matriz y lo he realizado con el condicional de if. Pero lo más dificil viene cuando hay que controlar las esquinas, ya que las coordenadas no son 8 si la persona selecciona una fila y columna de la esquina y da error fatal. Me estoy volviendo loca y no se que aplicar para controlar las esquinas y resolver esto de una vez. Necesito ayuda si alguien me la pudiera dar estaria muy agradecida. Muchas gracias!!

Esta es la parte del código a la cual me refiero:

```
boolean comprobar = false;
        do {

            System.out.println("Escoja la fila que quieras seleccionar (debe ser a partir del 1 y como máximo el numero que usted haya colocado en dificultad)");
            int fila = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Escoja la columna que quieras seleccionar (debe ser a partir del 1 y como máximo el numero que usted haya colocado en dificultad)");
            int columna = sc.nextInt();
            fila--;
            columna--;


/*

            if (fila < dificultad || fila > dificultad || columna < dificultad || columna > dificultad ) {
                System.out.println("Error debe seleccionar un numero dentro del rango escogido");
            }
            }

*/
            int contadorMinas = 0;


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila - 1][columna - 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila - 1][columna] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila - 1][columna + 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila][columna + 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila + 1][columna + 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;

            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila + 1][columna] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila + 1][columna - 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila][columna - 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila][columna] == 0) {
                matrizPrimeraBuscaMinas[fila][columna] = letraO;
                System.out.println("Seguir jugando, no hay ninguna mina.");
                System.out.println(contadorMinas);


            } else {
                matrizPrimeraBuscaMinas[fila][columna] = letraX;
                comprobar = true;

                System.out.println("\033[31m GAME OVER");
                System.out.println("\033[37m");


            }

            for (int i = 0; i < matrizPrimeraBuscaMinas.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrizPrimeraBuscaMinas[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print((char) matrizPrimeraBuscaMinas[i][j] + "  ");
                }
                System.out.println();

            }

        }
                while (comprobar == false) ;
                System.out.println("Fin del juego");

            }
        }
```

Comment: que error te marca? cuál es tu código?

Comment: if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila - 1][columna - 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila - 1][columna] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila - 1][columna + 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


            if (matrizSegundaBuscaMinas[fila][columna + 1] == 1) {
                contadorMinas++;
            }


        -------------------------

Comment: Uf perdona, veo que se escribe todo comprimido no se como ponerlo para que se entienda el código. Esto es un ejemplo de la matriz teniendo en cuenta los lados en caso de que la persona seleccione una fila y columna central. El problema como digo es si selecciona una posición del borde, que el algoritmo que he hecho no puede contemplar los alrededores de una parte y por eso da error y necesito aplicar algo para que no falle eso.

Comment: usa el [edit] y ponlo en la pregunta para que la gente pueda verlo :D

Comment: hecho!! ya lo he puesto

Comment: que error arroja al posicionarse en una esquina?

Comment: Ahora te indico!! Voy a probarlo de nuevo para que aparezca y te muestro

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3 at BuscaMinas.main(BuscaMinas.java:82)

Comment: toma en cuenta que a las variables fila y columna siempre le restas 1, así que, si es el extremo superior izquierdo, va a querer buscar la posición -1,-1 de tu matriz, la cual no existe

Comment: Y como añado esto teniendo en cuenta las 4 esquinas existentes del tablero, en mi codigo de if's? es que llevo mucho dandole a la cabeza y no logro resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es una excepción de indices. ¿a qué me refiero con esto? simple, supongamos tu matriz, hablando de posiciones, esta así:

```
[0-0], [0-1], [0-2]
[1-0], [1-1], [1-2]
[2-0], [2-1], [2-2]
```

Entonces, si quieres acceder a una posición, tiene que ser una de las mostradas en la matriz, supongamos que en tu sistema, como está planteado, ingreso `0` para `fila`, y `0` para `columna`. Lo primero que haces es restar 1 a ambos valores, por lo cual, fila y columna pasarían a ser `-1` y `-1` respectivamente.

¿El problema?
en la matriz de ejemplo no existe la posición -`1,-1`
luego, en los if, todavía le haces fila-1, y columna -1, lo cual haría que, al comparar en el if, el 0 original sería `-2` y `-2`.

¿Cómo solucionarlo?
simplemente no restes nada, no hay necesidad de hacerlo. solo crea tu aplicación considerando que todos las matrices empiezan en 0.

Espero que me haya explicado y te sea de ayuda

Comment: Si muchas gracias! Creo que te he entendido pero no estoy del todos segura, podrias ponerme el if que indicas de ejemplo, por favor? Gracias!